# Why Java class Cipher produce the same result in encrypt and decrypt mode on Android platform?

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to use Java class **Cipher** to encrypt/decrypt some of my data. But I'm confused why the same result is produced in encrypt and decrypt mode. Below is my code:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
KeyPair keyPair = generator.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

byte[] data = "12345".getBytes();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);

Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] decrypted = cipher2.doFinal(data);
```

Here the **encrypted** has exactly same content with **decrypted**. It really confused me why same result is produced regardless of what mode I'm using.

**What I have tried?**

If I use **Cipher.getInstance("DES")** to decrypt **"12345".getBytes()**, exception will be thrown.

Does it mean class **Cipher** can automatically detect whether encrypt or decrypt should be used(ignore *mode* parameter that I've specified when initialize the Cipher class) when using RSA?

Really appreciate for your help.

===Update===
My bad, looks Java has different behavior with Android. I should limit my question to Android platform only. If I run the above code as a normal Java application, **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error** will be thrown when decrypting "123456".

===Update===

Comment: There is no difference between plain text byte content and encrypted form byte content thus there is no "autodetection".

Comment: Can you show us that there is indeed the same output?

Answer (score 1):

First of all RSA is **asymetric** thus you use public key to encrypt and private key decrypt.

Second, those do not produce the same output.

```
 KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    KeyPair keyPair = generator.genKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

    byte[] data = "12345".getBytes();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
    System.out.println(new String(encrypted));

    Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher2.doFinal(encrypted);
    System.out.println(new String(decrypted));
```

with the output of

> D=1��� 12345

Third, there is no autodetection, but cipher can detect that decrypt material is corrupted or invalid - wrong pading in your case causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know a little about RSA, here I just want to use the same key to do encrypt and decrypt. I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: RSA is not your candidate then. DES on the other hand could do the trick.

Comment: `new String(encrypted)` doesn't really make sense. If you want to display bytes you should use hex or base64 encoding.